# Kotlin - Super primary Constructor?

Tags: kotlin

IntelliJ IDEA is complaining about the constructor.

> Convert to primary constructor

How would one go about doing that in this example?

```
class Turtle : ActorBeta {
constructor() : super()

override fun act(dt: Float) {
    super.act(dt)

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT))
        this.moveBy(-1f, 0f)
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT))
        this.moveBy(1f, 0f)
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP))
        this.moveBy(0f, 1f)
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN))
        this.moveBy(0f, -1f)
    }
}
```

Comment: Press Alt-Enter to apply the conversion automatically.

Comment: @yole This removes the super in the constructor altogether. Does this mean to say it was unnecessary all along?

Comment: Yes, the constructor was entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @yole Thank you.

Comment: Please consider deleting the question or answering your own question